# A question on partial fractions

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I have the given function which I must convert to partial fractions:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}
\end{equation}

and I thought that I should prepare this as:

\begin{equation}
\frac{A}{(x+i)}+\frac{Bx}{x^2+1}+\frac{Cx}{x^2+9}+\frac{D}{x+3i}
\end{equation}

But this is clearly wrong, because [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B1Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29i%20%2B%20x%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%291-i%5C%2841%29%20%5C%2840%293i%20%2B%20x%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29x-3i%5C%2841%29%5D) says that it must be in the form:

\begin{equation}
\frac{A}{x+i}+\frac{B}{x+3i}+\frac{C}{x+i}
\end{equation}

Is there a trick on how to identify the correct partial fractions, when the denominator clearly has a factorized complex 4th order polynomial as such?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) and especially all the examples given there.

Comment: Yes, this is all about reducibility, but why is not $( x-i )$ in the fractions then, since it is in the factors?

Comment: Because what you input into Wolfram was wrong. Somewhere you had $1 - i$ instead of $x - i$.

Comment: Great, thanks for this!

Comment: So one can conclude that since $x^2-1$ is reducible to both (x+i) and (x-i), then we only write the two factors, and not the quadratic form in the denominator? Was it not reducible, then we had to write out all the forms of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are attempting to use complex numbers here.  Simply let $u = x^2$ and this becomes:

$$\frac{u}{(u + 1)(u + 9)}$$

For the decomposition, use:
$$\frac{A}{u + 1} + \frac{B}{u + 9} = \frac{u}{(u + 1)(u + 9)}$$

This yields:

$$ Au + 9A + Bu + B = u$$

Separating out the $u$ and non-$u$ portions gives us:

$$ Au + Bu = u $$

and

$$ 9A + B = 0 $$

We can solve for $A$ in the first one as:
$$ A = 1 - B $$

Then substitute it in:

$$ 9(1 - B) + B = 0 \\
9 - 9B + B = 0 \\ 
9 - 8B = 0 \\
8B = 9 \\
B = \frac{9}{8}$$

Which means $A = -\frac{1}{8}$.

So your integration becomes:

$$\frac{-\frac{1}{8}}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{\frac{9}{8}}{x^2 + 9}$$

You can then use $arctan$ for the integration.

Comment: Much easier indeed. Thanks for this, I will bear it in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Here is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{2}}{(x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 9)} & = \frac{(x^{2} + 1) - 1}{(x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 9)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{x^{2} + 9} - \frac{1}{(x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 9)}
\end{align*}

The last expression, by its turn, can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 9)} & = \frac{1}{8}\times\frac{8}{(x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 9)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{8}\times\frac{(x^{2} + 9) - (x^{2} + 1)}{(x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 9)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{8}\times\left[\frac{1}{x^{2} + 1} - \frac{1}{x^{2} + 9}\right]
\end{align*}

Hence the original expression can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{2}}{(x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 9)} = -\frac{1}{8(x^{2} + 1)} + \frac{9}{8(x^{2} + 9)}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

The 'right' partial fraction decomposition
is rather
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(x) 
&=&
\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)} \\
&=&
\frac{x^2}{(x-i)(x+i)(x-3i)(x+3i)}\\
&=&
\frac{A}{x-i}+ 
\frac{B}{x+i}+
\frac{C}{x-3i}+
\frac{D}{x+3i}
\end{eqnarray*}
It holds
$$
A 
= [\phi(x)(x-i)]_{x=+i}
= \frac{i^2}{(i+i)(i^2+9)}
= \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{i}{2}
$$
and its conjugate
$$
B 
= [\phi(x)(x+i)]_{x=-i}
= \frac{(-i)^2}{(-i-i)((-i)^2+9)}
= \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{-i}{2}
$$
The rest is similar.